# Doing math with numbers in a list

Tags: python, for-loop

i want to be able to add, subtract, divide, multiply etc with integers in a list and in order.

I know you can use sum() to add, but i also want to be able to subtract, etc in order... so i tried making a for loop idk if thats the right thing to do, but it doesn't give me the right output and it really confuses me because it really seems like it should work. I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this or explain why its not giving me the same output as i expected.

```
my_list = [100, 15, 3]
for i in my_list:
    i -= i
print(i)

# 100 - 15 - 3 = 82
# Wanted output: 82
# Actual output: 0



my_list = [100, 15]
for i in my_list:
    i += i
print(i)

# 100 + 15 = 115
# Wanted output: 115
# Actual output: 30
```

Comment: `i` gets reassigned during every iteration of the loop. `i` will always be the current value from the list. You can't use `i` both as the value to add/subtract and also to hold the final sum. You'll need a separate variable to add to/subtract from.

Comment: First off, not knowing something yet isn't "stupid." Second, that's not how for loops work. Review your textbook on how to use a for loop. The temporary variable i should not be changed in the loop or used outside the loop.

Comment: Just as an unsolicited word of advice, it's good to play around a lot with the most basic blocks. Even before "trying to do math on a list", experiment with variables and control flow, to the point where you understand them inside and out and are bored stiff. There's something called the 80-20 rule - one variant of it is "20% of what you know is enough for 80% of what you do." A consequence of that is that mastery of the 20% is more valuable than familiarity with the other 80%. The people who seem smart are the ones who really understand what they learned in kindergarten. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main issues with your code:

1. `i` can't be your loop variable and the sum, because it will be overwritten all the time. So make two variables.
2. Your first task is different from the second. The sum is easy: take all the values of the list and add them, so the order is irrelevant. For your subtraction it's different because you have to take the first value and subtract all others, so it's basically `+100-15-3`, which means that also the order of the values in the list matter.

There are more elegant ways to solve it, but for the beginning this should be better to understand.

```
my_list = [100, 15, 3]


my_difference = my_list[0] #initialize with the first value of your list
my_list_sub = my_list[1:] #make a new list with the remaining numbers

for val in my_list_sub:
    my_difference=my_difference-val
print(my_difference)


my_list = [100, 15]
my_sum = 0 #initialize your sum with 0

for val in my_list:
    my_sum=my_sum+val
print(my_sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out: The "running"/temporary variable is overwritten in every loop. You can try this out with a simple test:

```
for entry in [0, 'a', 13.37]:
    print(entry)
```

It's always a good idea of trying out what happens in simple cases to learn what is going on.

But your idea of solving this with a loop is absolutely fine. If you want to re-use this functionallity later, it is also nice to wrap that in a function.

Assume integer values `my_values = [100, 50, 123, 51, 124, 121]` in the following examples.

Lets first tacle the sum.

```
def calculate_sum(values: list) -> int:
    result = 0
    for entry in values:
        result += entry
    return result
```

Check that it does what we want with

```
print(calculate_sum(my_values))
print(sum(my_values))
```

Now difference is 'almost' like summing up, but you want to sum up all values but the first one, and then compute the difference to the first one (`a-b-c-d = a-(b+c+d)`). Great, that we have already a method for summing up stuff, so we could simply do

```
def calculate_difference(values: list) -> int:
    first, *other = values
    return first - calculate_sum(other)
```

Note the `*`-marker in front of the `other` variable. When assigning a list two multiple variables, they are "unpacked"  by python. Thus `a, b, c = [0, 1, 2]` would assign `0` to `a` and so on. However, when we do `a, b = [0, 1, 2]`, then python complains because there are `too many variables to unpack` in the list (3 > 2). With the asterisk we simply tell python to put all other values, not used so far,  into this special variable again. `a, b, *rest = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` is also possible.

---

Ok, computing the product is as easy as summing up, just replace `+=` by `*=` in the method. And for the quotient we can do the same as for the difference, since `a * 1/b * 1/c * 1/d = a / (b*c*d)`. However, note that if the divisor is zero, python will raise an Error `DivisionByZero`, as this is not legal. Also, the result of the method is `float` and no longer `int`.